# Can you determine the size of the data in a PYODBC cursor after query execution before fetching the data from cursor?

Tags: python, pyodbc, database-cursor

I want to use batching through `cursor.fetchmany` instead of `cursor.fetchall` only when necessary to avoid out of memory erros, so is there a way to get the size of the data the in cursor after query execution and before fetching, in order to batch only if the data exceeds a certain size.

Comment: Seems like you could infer from either the table schema and/or the first row